# On-chain vs Off-chain NFT art platforms

Tags: blockchain, erc-721, nft, off-chain

In [this thread](https://twitter.com/beaniemaxi/status/1372998542827094022), an NFT cryptoart collector with deep pockets named beanie said,

> I have bought a few pieces on FND cause they were significantly
> cheaper, but now realize they were priced that way for a reason.
>
> SR on-chain provenance is critical for galleries and investors.
>
> The price premium is probably still understated.

and adds

> The SuperRare platform is the on chain marketplace, just like Larva
> Labs (CryptoPunks).
>
> This is CRITICAL and adds immense value in so many ways.

What does he mean by the [Foundation.app](http://foundation.app) (FND) platform being off-chain and the [SuperRare](http://superrare.co) (SR) platform being on-chain? From what I understand, there is no economical way to store 5MB+ jpeg files on any blockchain at the moment so I doubt SuperRare even does what he is claiming. What is he really getting at?

Besides, doesn't FND and SR both upload images to the InterPlanetary File System (IPFS), meaning that they are both off-chain?

Comment: If you're aware of where SuperRare or FND maintain their smart contracts, please post a link here, so we can all take a look at the code.

Comment: the visual content of all minted NFTs on both platforms point to IPFS addresses

Comment: The thread isn't about on-chain or off-chain, but curated vs non-curated content.

Comment: what are u talking about

Answer (score 0):

As Ismael points to in the comments, it would seem that the author of the linked comment in the OP's question was not pointing to SuperRare being on-chain and Foundation off-chain, but was emphasizing that the value of SuperRare as a curator. The "on-chain" provenance comment likely means that being able to point to an NFTs on-chain history means it can be traced back to where it was purchased from on-chain, and having been in SuperRare is part of what one is purchasing when they purchase such an NFT (in the thread author's opinion.)

There's something we should really unpack here as an additional note on the question: NFTs, according to the ERC-721 (and 1155) standard that they are based on, do not (generally) "include" a JPEG or other image. There is generally a field in the NFT that contains some kind of pointer (if you look at the [standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721), this is the extension called the Metadata extension) traditionally a URL or IPFS (or similar) hash, to a JSON. The JSON, in turn, links to the media. This is very significant, as it means in many cases that the media can become either unlinked (in the case of the JSON pointing to a centralized IPFS gateway, [for example](https://twitter.com/jonty/status/1372163423446917122)) or even actively changed (in the case of it pointing to someone's traditional web site, [for example](https://twitter.com/neitherconfirm/status/1369285946198396928)). That's a bit tangential, but very useful in terms of understanding NFTs.

Comment: yes, i know that NFTs point to the image elsewhere. and that elsewhere is *off-chain* for both the FND and SR platforms. your answer is moot, because FND also has, what you call, "on-chain history". just look at any NFT minted and listed there. Beanie was making a distinction between FND and SR, but his claim makes no sense and makes no reference to facts. the question hasn't been answered, and this answer is only speculating about the meaning of "on-chain provenance".

Comment: From the root tweet linked: "SuperRare has a distinct price premium because it is professionally curated, OG, and has an active secondary marketplace." The second tweet you quote in a part of the tweet that you truncated mentions that they believe when you buy from SuperRare that you are also collecting the platform, which was the context of the comparison to CryptoPunks (and that having a SuperRare NFT is superior in their opinion to one whose provenance is from FNC). Are you reading these passages differently than us? If so, could you please elaborate?

Comment: i am only inquiring on a purely blockchain-technological standpoint when i say "on-chain" and "off-chain". If the quote is not referring to these concepts how they are *intended* to be used, but instead twisting around the meaning to imply "curation", which these terms DO NOT convey, nor do they make any sense in this parlance, then the quotes are completely misleading and uninformed with no *blockchain-technological* content whatsoever